# Single page 301 redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a strange problem with 301 redirects through .htaccess, and i cannot seem to find the answer to it.

I want to make a permanent redirect of a single page, which goes as follows:

Old page: http://mydomain.com//index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=1&Itemid=225

New page: http://mydomain.com/banen

My .htaccess file looks like this. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
    #####################################################

    ##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
    #Options +FollowSymLinks

    #
    #  mod_rewrite in use

    RewriteEngine On

    ########## Begin - 301 Redirect old site pages

    Redirect 301 /index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=1&Itemid=225 http://mydomain.com/banen

    ########## End - 301 Redirects

    ########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
    ## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
    ## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
    #
    ## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
    #
    #Order allow,deny
    #Deny from all
    #Satisfy all
    #
    ## End of deny access to extension xml files
    # Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
    # Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
    # Block out any script that includes a  tag in URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (|%3E) [NC,OR]
    # Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
    # Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
    # Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
    RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
    #
    ########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

    RewriteBase /

    ########## Begin rewrite http:// to http://www.
    #
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    #
    ########## End

    #  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
    #  is not directly related to physical file paths.
    #  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

    # RewriteBase /

    ########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
    #
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    #
    # If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
    # has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
    # and the request is for root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
    # requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    #
    ########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Comment: It's confusing about where you are trying to go _from_ and where _to_. Are you looking at the "new" _incoming_ URI to be "SEO" style `/banen`, and it maps to a "real" URI `/index.php?option=...`? In that case, your redirect is backwards. Or, do you have the incoming URI as `/index.php?option=...` and you want to go to a real page `/banen`?

Comment: I have an incoming URL as index.php?option=... and the real new page is /banen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of first `Redirect 301` rule have this `mod_rewrite` rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=1&Itemid=225$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /banen/? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^layout=blog$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^component/content/category/3$ /gaester/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How about this redirect:
Old link: http://mydomain.com/component/content/category/3?layout=blog
New link: http://mydomain.com/gaester

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Comment: May I ask if you know the answer the my next problem?

Old link: mydomain.com/component/content/category/3?layout=blog 

New link: mydomain.com/gaester 

Thank you in advance.